# Changing probability in java

Tags: java, probability

I have been trying to write this program for a simple fighting simulator and a task I have to do is ask the user for the percentage of low, medium, and high attacks in a fighting round.

So for example, the user inputs low = 50%, medium = 30%, and high = 20%. Now my question stems from here. How do make it so that in one round the program will print low 50% of the time, medium 30% of the time, and high 20% of the time?

Comment: Youre going to have to post some example code for anyone to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Without giving you the exact Java code, here is what you need to do:

1. Create a set of intervals. In your case, it is `[0, 0.5>`, `[0.5, 0.8>`; `[0.8, 1.0>`.
2. Generate a random number between 0 and 1
3. See what interval it falls in. It will fall into the first interval 50% of the time, the second interval 30% of the time, and the third interval 20% of the time

You can figure it out from here?

Afterthought: in your case, the values that the user inputs add up to 100%. In general that may not be true; then you compute the "apparent intervals" first, and finally scale them to a maximum of 1. Let's say the user entered 50,30,30% (can't do their math...). Your intervals would be

```
0, .5
.5, .8
.8, 1.1
```

And you would have to divide everything by `1.1` to get the right intervals. OR you could multiply your random number by `1.1`.

Comment: Because the random number is in the range [0, 1>, shouldn't your intervals be [0, 0.5> [0.5, 0.8> [0.8, 1>?

Comment: @ILMTitan you are right - edited.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can think of is to create an array with equal proportion of your requirements (here I created 10 strings with 5 lows, 3 mediums and 2 highs)

```
String[] probabilities = { "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "medium", "medium", "medium", "high", "high };
```

Then use a random number to pick one element from the array

```
Random random = new Random(); // might want to give it a seed here
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(probabilities.length);
String probability = probabilities[randomIndex];
```

With large sampling this should give you the desired distribution.

Comment: nice and easy solution